# new object() undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

In my attempts to learn JavaScript, I came up with this canvas drawing idea. Basically, I am storing coordinates in an array and the script will draw buttons on the canvas automatically. Each button requires 8 coordinates, `x1`,`y1`,`x2`,`y2`,etc... (I might even make those buttons work as links later ;p). The problem I am having is, this doesn't run at all and chrome inspector console says "`object is undefined`" at this line: "`button = new object();`"

Any help is appreciated. 
Leo

```
function loadMenu() {
    //Initialize Canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("menu_canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Button Data
    var buttonData = [59, 0, 19, 40, 128, 40, 168, 0];
    //Create Buttons
    var i = 1;
    while (i < buttonData.length) {
        button = new object();
        for (var j = i; j != i + 8; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                button.X[j] = buttonData[j - 1];
            } else {
                button.Y[j] = buttonData[j - 1];
            }
        }
        drawButton(button);
        i = i + 8;
    }
    //Begin drawing buttons
    function drawButton(button) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(button.X1, buttonX2);
        for (k = 2; k != 4; k++) {
            context.lineTo(buttonX[k], buttonY[k]);
        }
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `new Object();` not `new object();`. Javascript is case-sensitive. But really, you want to be using `{}`.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. The function is called `Object`, not `object`. Or just use an object literal: `{}`. But you will run into another problem: It does not look like you are defining `button.X` and `button.Y` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must capitalize it:

```
button = new Object();
```

Javascript is case sensitive.

Alternatively, you could use the object literal (as noted by Nile):

```
button = {};
```

Comment: or use the object literal `{}`.